# Period placement in a sentence containing both parantheses and quotes

Tags: quotes, parentheses

Which of the following is correct:

> 1. (This is a "test").
> 2. (This is a "test.")
> 3. (This is a "test".)

Answer (score 3):

Let's first look at the parentheses (*Example #1*). As is brought out in [**this answer**](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/2127/5438) (only the relevant point has been included):

> Examine the material enclosed by parentheses. Is it an entire sentence? If so, place the period inside the closing parenthesis.

Since *"This is a test"* is a complete sentence, the period belongs inside of the parentheses, so the first example is incorrect (though, people will definitely still understand you even if you are "slightly incorrect" in that case).

The other two examples you posted will vary depending on if you are reading American English or British English. *Example #2* is preferred in Britain, *Example #3* is preferred in the United States. See the following answer for more details: [*How should I punctuate around quotes?*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/1614/5438)

Comment: I suspect the mismatched quotation marks are a typo (and it's not breaking any HTML rules that I'm aware of). Could you please update your answer to address the position of the period in that example?

Comment: @BraddSzonye Oh, I see now; the parentheses are part of the question (that's what I get for skimming the title).

Comment: @BraddSzonye And regarding HTML, yes, I know, but I hate that `<br>` is perfectly valid syntax. I feel `<br/>` should be a requirement, and I stubbornly refuse to acknowledge that it isn't. ;)

Comment: As has been pointed out before, the term 'British English' is misleading. Different styles are _not_ country-specific.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Do you have a link to where that has been pointed out before? If that is the case, I would like to include that information in the answer.

Comment: While quotation punctuation isn't universal in the UK or the US, I think it's fair to say that it's generally preferred that way.

Comment: In the thread [How to correctly use double quotation marks at the end of a sentence?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/127618/how-to-correctly-use-double-quotation-marks-at-the-end-of-a-sentence/127675#127675) . I usually try to use a logical approach leading to fewer possibilities for confusion; this may lead to double punctuation at the end of quotes, for which I can find 'authoritative' support. (One must realise that some quotes are of direct speech, which carries no punctuation, while others are of already-punctuated material: tricky if originally in an alternative style.)

Comment: I also think that those people who use the 'British / American' terminology here would say you've got them the [wrong way round](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/quotation_(speech)_marks_punctuation_in_or_out.htm) in your final paragraph.